# Blocking interaction between child and main parent form vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, parent-child

At the moment, I have a project I'm working on with a menu that opens a new window. Annoyingly, when the new window is opened, it just does everything the main parent window does that the new window is opened up from. I want to be able to have the new window be able to do it's own thing and not just share what ever the parent is doing. Is there anything I can do at a button's click to give this form some kind of attribute that disallows this?

Comment: Be more specific. This thing, that thing - very hard to understand.

Comment: thats not normal - show the code where the child form is created and shown

Answer (score 0):

You can use seperate form. the working of each form will depend on what you specified in that particular form.. You can use the MDI form. and call all child forms under the mdi form. the child form will open in seperate window under MDI form.

you can simply call the child form as

```
Private Sub MembersToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MembersToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim xfrm As New childForm
    xfrm.MdiParent = Me
    xfrm.Show()
End Sub
```